# How can I create a collaborative work environment on Apex Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to create a collaborative work environment to create a database for an advanced database class. I am thinking of something along the lines of a Google Drive of Apex Oracle.

Is there some code that can be implemented? We all use the server provided by the school. However if I insert table a into the database, my classmate cannot access table unless they create their own table a. Can this be remedied?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options I can think of.

### As of the database

Option 1:

- create only one database user; create all tables, views, whatever you want

Option 2:

- create as many database users as number of students; each of them would have their own set of tables, views, whatever

### As of Apex

Option 1:

1. create one workspace and map it to the schema created in the first *database* option
2. create as many developers as needed; all of them will be working in the same workspace. They can all be working on the same application (probably not a good idea), or each of them can have their own application
3. it means that all of them would be sharing the same tables (so if someone deletes all rows from some table, they'll be gone for all developers)

Option 2:

1. create as many workspaces as number of students; map each workspace to its own database schema (created in the second *database* option)
2. create one developer per workspace
3. each student would work on their own tables, on their own application, in their own workspace

### What to do?

It is possible to use any of the "cross-join" combinations of those options (database 1 + apex 1; or database 1 + apex 2; etc.).

From my point of view, I'd go for **database 2 + apex 2**.